# how does repo mirror known full set of git repositories?

Tags: repo

how does repo mirror known full set of git repositories?
When we use '--mirror' as parameter for repo init command, repo will git clone all possible git repositories to local.

I wonder how repo known the full set of git repositories? If a git repository is removed from one branch of manifest.git, how does repo mirror command aware it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The `repo sync .. --mirror` command isn't aware of multiple branches of a mirror repository. See [this answer](https://groups.google.com/g/repo-discuss/c/QBZWw60KSgw) by Shawn Pearce - one of the repo contributors - on mirror behaviour in 2009 that by looking at [the code](https://android.googlesource.com/tools/repo/+/5951e3043f8d9567bfcd6e0f328ae057e1dfad11/subcmds/sync.py) still holds true.

> > Does it take all the trees in the most recent commit from master branch?
>
> Yes
>
> > or does it also mirror trees which could be referenced in a different branch, or an older commit?
>
> No, it doesn't do any of that.

Incidentally, at least [AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/mirror/manifest) and [Lineages](https://github.com/LineageOS/mirror) mirror manifest repos offer one branch only.

If no other filename is given, the `default.xml` holds repositories (read "projects") that are then mirrored with `refs/tags/* refs/heads/*` therein - all tags and branches at time of clone.

A counter example would  be TheMuppets [manifests repo](https://github.com/TheMuppets/manifests) for vendor binary blobs. It offers at time of writing a `default.xml` with suitable project list for a mirror in its `master` and `mirror` branches and a script to regenerate the file. To avoid confusion of the repos role, they would've been better served to offer this separately at `TheMuppets/mirror`.